# Structured pursuit of an aim

Tags: idioms, neologisms

Is there an English word that denotes the structured and deliberate pursuit of a course of action in order to achieve a goal?

Comment: ***Single-mindedness**?* ***Focus**?* How about just *[having a] **plan**?*

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We need considerably more context than you have provided to supply a definitive answer; please see our guidance on [single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). More generally, I would encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help].

Answer (score 1):

You could go for **plan of action** - An organized programme of measures to be taken in order to achieve a goal. [[Oxford Dictionaries]](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plan_of_action_(or_campaign_or_attack))

Or alternatively, Oxford Dictionaries gives the words **campaign** and **attack** on the same page.

> These five goals were discussed to determine a plan of action to
>   achieve them. *[same source]*

Comment: **Campaign** is in common usage. Just ask any politician or military tactician.

Comment: What is the goal of your comment?  What are you trying to point out?

Comment: **Attack** is far less commonly used, except in military matters.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I agree, but nevertheless they are both potentially viable options.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for **"project"**?

> - "a plan or proposal for accomplishing something."[**¹**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/project)

In the scientific environment the word **"protocol"** is often used.

> - "a detailed plan of a scientific or medical experiment, treatment, or procedure."[**²**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/protocol)

**"road map"** also comes to mind.

> - "a detailed plan to guide progress toward a goal."[**³**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/road%20map)

Example sentences:

- "Here is the road map to our financial independence."
- "We need a project for urban renewal."
- "The methodology section is the most important part of the protocol. It should include detailed information on the interventions to be made, procedures to be used, measurements to be taken, observations to be made, laboratory investigations to be done etc." [**WHO**](https://www.who.int/rpc/research_ethics/format_rp/en/)